# 20 hour lay over time in LHR airport London, will they allow me to stay in airport for 20 hours

Tags: layovers, lhr

What is the maximum time permitted to stay in airport ? I got a 20 hour lay over in Heathrow (LHR), but in LHR website it was mentioned as overnight stay not permitted.

Comment: do you have a visa? I.e. will you be in transit only, or will you be able to clear customs?

Comment: ya got landside transit visa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have a landside transit visa, this is easy - yes, you can.

A friend of mine recently blogged about [spending 24 hours in Heathrow](http://www.thetravellingeditor.com/my-24-hours-in-heathrow-night/) (he got the wrong day for his flight), and he had no problems, and was certainly not alone.

It's worth noting, however, that [SleepingInAirports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/londonheathrow.htm#.UcKjuZzcPyU) gives it a poor review, and you may find it easier to grab a hotel, either one of the airport ones, or even one in town (Earl's court is only an hour away).

Comment: Thank you, your answer was so helpful. and if chance i want to go for sight seeing in london, two or three places in my lay over time, can you suggest me best way to do that, like any cab or city tours any thing available, i will land at 12.30 and my connecting flight is at 7.05 next morning.

Comment: From the airport, just hop on the tube (underground trains) straight to central London.  See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/7-hour-layover-in-lhr-enough-time-to-visit-london-for-a-couple-of-hours?rq=1) for examples of how to do this.