# Do I need Transit Visa to visit London for 4-5 hours during layover?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, lhr

I am an Indian citizen. I am going to study in Canada with a study-permit. I am planning to have my flight via London. I've a layover there at London for almost 9 hours. Is it wise to visit the city for 4-5 hours during the layover? Additionally do I need a Transit Visa to visit the city? or do I need a General Visitor Visa for this short-trip at London?

**Edits:**
Arriving and departing both the flights are from London Heathrow airport.

DATV suggests that if I am heading to Canada, I don't need DATV.
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no

Visitor in Transit Visa suggests that I can pass border control with this Visa. I may also get a Transit without Visa concession if I satisfy this three:

- you arrive and depart by air
- have a confirmed onward flight which leaves within 24 hours
- have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)

And I am also heading to Canada, this also can help me to get this concession.

So, do I need a Visitor in Transit Visa to visit the city? At least website suggests that. However, I'm not sure as no one can tell it with confirmation. Hope someone helps out here.

Comment: Would both the flight into and out of London be from the same London airport, or might you fly into one and onwards from the other?

Comment: This is a combination of 2 questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/london-heathrow-airport-do-i-need-a-transit-visa?rq=1, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/7-hour-layover-in-lhr-enough-time-to-visit-london-for-a-couple-of-hours?rq=1

Comment: @Gagravarr edited the question. Please see.

Comment: @Karlson I read those. However, I'm not sure which Visa I should choose. If I don't even consider to leave the airport, then also do I need a Visa? If yes, which one? DATV or Visitor in Transit Visa?

If I choose to leave the airport for 4-5 hours, can I choose Visitor in Transit Visa and just roam around the city and come back to the airport to board to the next flight? or will I be needing General Visitor Visa in that case?


https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes
This link suggests that I may apply for Visitor in Transit Visa and can cross border control to visit the city.

Comment: @soham.m17 What is assumed with regard to a transit visa is that you ONLY wish to travel to the next airport. I'm not sure, but I believe you will be asked why do you wish to leave the airport when the flight for your next destination leaves from the same airport.

Answer (score 9):

If you wish to visit London, present at the UK border:

- Passport open at the page with the Canadian visa
- Filled-out landing Card
- Connecting boarding pass (or e-ticket if you don't have it)

You'll be able to enter the UK and stay until 23:59 the next day.

If fulfilling these conditions, you do **not** need a visa.

Comment: If a visa is not needed, which page is the visa page?

Comment: @MadHatter The page with the Canadian visa

Comment: This is the correct answer